# Magento 2 webapi INR error While place order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I got an error while placing order in magento 2. But my order is placed in magento 2 backend. I got an error like this.

```
main.CRITICAL: Exception: Report ID: webapi-56b84c8611046; Message: Notice: Undefined index: INR in app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Observer/SalesOrderPlaceAfterObserver.php on line 303 in vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194 Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(163): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

Kindly help me .

Comment: Hi bala Please raise a ticket at https://webkul.com/ticket and we will look in to the issues . thanks

Comment: Also in the latest upgarde of the module issue has been solved .

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the Webkul Marketplace extension, you should contact the developer for support.